# Display normal confirm messages to ext js

Tags: extjs

How can I display Ext js confirm messages to replace my normal confirm messages.??I want to replace all confirm messages to Ext JS.
Help

```
var strAlert = "Are you sure you want.."; 
if ( confirm( strAlert ) ) { 
   PrevSrc=event.srcElement.src; 
   event.srcElement.src="../images/loading.gif"; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out `Ext.MessageBox` class. http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/message-box/msg-box.html

Comment: Hi Sha,thanks for replying..but tat`s not wat I want,I have to change all my normal confirm messages to Ext js confirm messages,for that I tried to use following code,but that`s not working...window.confirm=function(btn,text)
{
Ext.Msg.confirm('confirm!', btn, function(btn, text){
  if(btn=='yes'){
      //Ext.Msg("i`m in");
   return true;
  }
  else{
    return false;
  }
         });
}

Comment: Please post the code you have in the question. And be more specific of what are you trying to replace with what.

Comment: okay...I`m sorry if i`m not clear..this is the code i`ve got now okay->var strAlert = "Are you sure you want.."; if ( confirm( strAlert ) ) { PrevSrc=event.srcElement.src; event.srcElement.src="../images/loading.gif"; }...but the confirm box which i get is of not ext js type,so I wanted to change the type to Ext JS....So I tried this code->window.confirm=function(btn,text) { Ext.Msg.confirm('confirm!', btn, function(btn, text){ if(btn=='yes'){ return true;} else{return false;}}); }..it`s not working...

Comment: This will not work as easy. In ExtJs Message box show() method is asynchronous - meaning it will return control to you code after it shown, not after user made his choice. You need to work with callback functions inside MessageBox.

Comment: Ohh okay sha...any other choice do i have?other than callback functions...because there are many where I`ve to do...